# Nmap: extract undesirable ports for sending mail with Batch and Blat

Tags: string, security, batch-file, nmap

## Context

I use `FINDSTR /C:"portid=" "scanports.xml"` to extract theses lines from a file:

```
<port protocol="tcp" portid="21"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="124"/><service name="ftp" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="22"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="124"/><service name="ssh" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="80"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="124"/><service name="http" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="443"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="124"/><service name="https" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="3389"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="124"/><service name="ms-term-serv" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
```

## Questions

- How to extract `21`, `22`, `80`, `443` and `3389` from this line?
- Same question for a random number in `[0-9]` except `21`, `22`, `80`, `443` and `3389`?

I want to send by email all opened ports usually not open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a second FINDSTR to filter out the "normally open" ports. The solution I show uses an external file to list the ports to exclude (the normally open ones). Alternatively the list could be specified on the command line as multiple `/C` options.

ignore.txt (edit as needed)

```
portid="21"
portid="22"
portid="80"
portid="443"
portid="3389"
```

`findstr /c:"portid=" test.txt | findstr /r /v /g:"ignore.txt"`

There is a bug with FINDSTR in that it may fail to find a match if there are multiple literal search strings of different lengths. That is the reason I chose to use the `/R` regular expression option.

If the format of the XML file is consistent then you can use FOR /F with DELIMS set to the quote character to pull out the 4th token. The syntax for specifying a FOR /F options with quote as a delimiter is odd: Normally you would do something like `"tokens=4 delims=,"`. But to include quote as a delimiter you have to do a bunch of escaping: `tokens^=4^ delims^=^"`.

Putting it all together you get

```
@echo off
for /f tokens^=4^ delims^=^" %%P in (
  'findstr /c:"portid=" test.txt ^| findstr /r /v /g:"ignore.txt"'
) do (
  echo unusual open port = %%P
)
exit /b
```

If the format (attribute order) of the XML can vary, then the solution is more complex. You first use an outer FOR /F to read the entire line into a variable. You use a SET * search and replace op to find the portid location within the string, and then a second FOR /F to parse out the actual port.

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%L in (
  'findstr /c:"portid=" test.txt ^| findstr /r /v /g:"ignore.txt"'
) do (
  set "ln=%%L"
  for /f delims^=^=^" %%A in ("!ln:*portid=!") do set port=%%A
  echo unusual open port = !port!
)
```

Once you have the port ids isolated you are in a position to build your mail message. I recommend using [Blat for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/blat/) to send your email.

Comment: Really sorry for abusing your time.

Answer (score 1):

You could use FOR/F for parsing lines.

```
FINDSTR /C:"portid=" "scanports.xml" > tmpFile.tmp

FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=>=" %%1 in (tmpFile.tmp) DO (
  echo %%~1
)
```

Comment: I just needed `21` and not `<port protocol="tcp" portid="21">`. But your answer helped me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a little cheating, but your batch file can call a VBScript script:

```
c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe //nologo scanports.vbs
```

Where scanports.vbs is the following script:

```
Option Explicit
Dim xml, port
Set xml = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xml.load "scanports.xml"
For Each port in xml.documentElement.selectNodes("//port")
  WScript.Echo port.getAttribute("portid")
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I finish my script with [**jeb's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9199741/652669) and [this link](http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/how-to-specify-quotes-as-delimiter/15313.html).

## Code:

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

REM Blat options:
SET blat="C:\Program Files (x86)\blat276\full\blat.exe"
SET server=127.0.0.1
SET port=25
SET from=x@x.com
SET to=y@y.com

FOR %%i IN (1,1,9) DO (  
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap\nmap.exe" server%%i.com -oX scanports%%i.xml

  FINDSTR /C:"portid=" scanports%%i.xml >> scanports%%itemp.txt

  FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN (scanports%%itemp.txt) DO (
    SET x=%%a
    SET x=!x:"=/!
    FOR /f "tokens=4,12 delims=/" %%a IN ("!x!") DO (
      IF NOT %%a==21 IF NOT %%a==22 IF NOT %%a==80 IF NOT %%a==443 IF NOT %%a==3389 (
        %blat% -server %server% -port %port% -f %from% -to %to% -html -s "Port ouvert sur server%%i" -body "Port %%a : %%b"
      )
    )
  )
  
  DEL scanports%%i.xml
  DEL scanports%%itemp.txt
)
```